# MLServer GRPC cannot reshape array of size 347 into shape (1,)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grpc, grpc-python, seldon-core

I am following the example to serve sklearn model https://github.com/SeldonIO/MLServer/blob/master/docs/examples/sklearn/README.md

I am able to train and genreate the model, and then do a REST call for the inference successfully. However, I am trying to craft a gRPC call now, and the only example I could find is this https://mlserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/custom-json/README.html?highlight=grpc#send-test-inference-request-grpc

However, this is using another model. SO I try to follow this example but replace it with inference request data from my current infer.py, please see `infer-grpc.py` below.

train.py

```
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))

# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# Split data into train and test subsets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data, digits.target, test_size=0.5, shuffle=False)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
import joblib

model_file_name = "mnist-svm.joblib"
joblib.dump(classifier, model_file_name)
```

infer.py (http)

```
import requests
# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))

# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# Split data into train and test subsets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data, digits.target, test_size=0.5, shuffle=False)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


x_0 = X_test[0:1]
inference_request = {
    "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "predict",
          "shape": x_0.shape,
          "datatype": "FP32",
          "data": x_0.tolist()
        }
    ]
}

endpoint = "http://localhost:8089/v2/models/mnist-svm/versions/v0.1.0/infer"
response = requests.post(endpoint, json=inference_request)

print(response.json())
```

infer-grpc.py

```
import mlserver.types
import requests
import json
import grpc
import mlserver.grpc.converters as converters
import mlserver.grpc.dataplane_pb2_grpc as dataplane
import mlserver.types as types
import requests
# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))

# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# Split data into train and test subsets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data, digits.target, test_size=0.5, shuffle=False)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


x_0 = X_test[0:1]



model_name = "mnist-svm"

ip = {"input": x_0.tolist()}


inputs_bytes = json.dumps(x_0.tolist()).encode("UTF-8")

print([len(inputs_bytes)])
print(inputs_bytes)

inference_request = types.InferenceRequest(
    inputs=[
        types.RequestInput(
            name="predict",
            shape=[len(inputs_bytes)],
            datatype="BYTES",
            data=[inputs_bytes],


        )
    ]
)




inference_request_g = converters.ModelInferRequestConverter.from_types(
    inference_request,
    model_name=model_name,
    model_version=None
)

grpc_channel = grpc.insecure_channel("localhost:8081")
grpc_stub = dataplane.GRPCInferenceServiceStub(grpc_channel)

response = grpc_stub.ModelInfer(inference_request_g)
response
```

throws an error:

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Unexpected <class 'ValueError'>: cannot reshape array of size 347 into shape (1,)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The V2 Inference Protocol lets you send tensors directly. Therefore, since you are trying to send a Numpy tensor, you should be able to encode it as (i.e. without the intermediate `json.dumps` step):

```py
inference_request = types.InferenceRequest(
    inputs=[
        types.RequestInput(
            name="predict",
            shape=x_0.shape,
            datatype="BYTES",
            data=x_0.tolist()
        )
    ]
)
```

Note that, since MLServer 1.1.0, you can also [use codecs to encode your payloads](https://mlserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/content-type.html#numpy-array). Therefore, you should also be able to do the following:

```
from mlserver.codecs import NumpyRequestCodec

inference_request = NumpyRequestCodec.encode_request(x_0)
```